# SQL - Create sumfunction which uses different timeinterval depending on which time it is

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sum

I am currently working with some data which I have a rather interesting challenge.

**Introduction and question:**

So I have a lot of timeseries data which is arranged as follows:

```
time                  | price
------------------------------
'2014-07-07 06:00:00' | 1100

'2014-07-07 07:00:00' |  900
```

I am basically interested in making a sum function which depends on the current time. It should be such that at 1300 hours the price from 6-12 should be summed. Then at 16 hours the sum from 6-12 should be added with the sum from 12-15, like shown below:

```
time                  | price | sum function
------------------------------------
'2014-07-07 08:00:00' | 1000  | NULL

'2014-07-07 09:00:00' | 1200  | NULL

'2014-07-07 10:00:00' | 1300  | NULL

'2014-07-07 11:00:00' | 700   | NULL

'2014-07-07 12:00:00' | 800   | NULL

'2014-07-07 13:00:00' | 2000  | 6000

'2014-07-07 14:00:00' | 3500  | 6000

'2014-07-07 15:00:00' | 2500  | 6000

'2014-07-07 16:00:00' | 1000  | 14000

'2014-07-07 17:00:00' | 500   | 14000
```

This means that assuming the time is 12:00:00, then I would like to make a function which at that time (and forward) sumerized the price values from 06:00-12:00. with a three hour step going forwad. I am not exactly sure what would be the best way to solve this problem I thought of following:

**Solutions**

Create a function which receives the current time and the last 12 hour of price data and simply makes the logic and return the function. The logic would then be as discussed. IF the time is between 00:00 - 12:00 the return would be NULL.

Do you have a better suggestions?

**System:**

MS SQL 2008 + MS Management Studi Express

**Question:**

How do I make a function which summerize price data dependent on the time?

**UPDATE:**

Based on Kevins answer (thanks kevin) I ended up using the `OUTER APPLY` and got it working in this simple example. Taking this to full scale still causes me problems since I dont have a table but a select statement:

`Select allValues.*, CASE WHEN DATEPART (HOUR, allValues.UTCHour) > 12 THEN bVal.lessThan12 ELSE 0 
from
(**A VERY large select statment**) allValues
OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT 
    sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART (HOUR, allValues.UTCHour) <= 12 THEN allValues.Measurement ELSE 0 END) lessThan12
) bVal`

Unfortunately this returns the error message: `Msg 4101 Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TimeSeries TABLE
(
    SeriesTime DATETIME,
    SeriesPrice INT
)

INSERT INTO @TimeSeries
( SeriesTime, SeriesPrice )
VALUES
('2014-07-07 06:00:00', 1100),
('2014-07-07 07:00:00', 900),
('2014-07-07 08:00:00', 1000),
('2014-07-07 09:00:00', 1200),
('2014-07-07 10:00:00', 1300),
('2014-07-07 11:00:00', 700),
('2014-07-07 12:00:00', 800),
('2014-07-07 13:00:00', 2000),
('2014-07-07 14:00:00', 3500),
('2014-07-07 15:00:00', 2500),
('2014-07-07 16:00:00', 1000),
('2014-07-07 17:00:00', 500);

SELECT 
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.SeriesTime) > 15 THEN e.LessThan15
         WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.SeriesTime) > 12 THEN d.LessThan12 ELSE NULL END AS SumFunction
FROM @TimeSeries t
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, SeriesTime) <= 12 THEN SeriesPrice ELSE 0 END) LessThan12
    FROM @TimeSeries
) d
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, SeriesTime) <= 15 
        THEN SeriesPrice ELSE 0 END) LessThan15
    FROM @TimeSeries
) e
```

I have two queries for the sums and then I use a case statement to pull the 3rd column based on the hour.  In your case above you were getting different results but when I sum up all of the values from 0 to 12pm I get 7000 not 6000, it's like your results are a 1000 off (maybe a typo in your post?)   Here is my output:

```
SeriesTime  SeriesPrice SumFunction
2014-07-07 06:00:00.000 1100    NULL
2014-07-07 07:00:00.000 900     NULL
2014-07-07 08:00:00.000 1000    NULL
2014-07-07 09:00:00.000 1200    NULL
2014-07-07 10:00:00.000 1300    NULL
2014-07-07 11:00:00.000 700     NULL
2014-07-07 12:00:00.000 800     NULL
2014-07-07 13:00:00.000 2000    7000
2014-07-07 14:00:00.000 3500    7000
2014-07-07 15:00:00.000 2500    7000
2014-07-07 16:00:00.000 1000    15000
2014-07-07 17:00:00.000 500     15000
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your input. I have already implemented with succes - thanks!

Comment: I noticed that when the day shifts to the next day I will get a problem. How should I consider this you think?

Comment: Just add  WHERE DATEPART(DAY, SeriesTime) = DATEPART(DAY, t.SeriesTime) AND DATEPART(YEAR, SeriesTime) = DATEPART(YEAR, t.SeriesTime) to both the queries inside the outer applys and then it will only sum for that day.

Comment: Suppose the table TimeSeries were a view and not a saved Table. Would it be possible to make the same function you think?

Comment: Yes you could use it just like a table

Comment: So, I am having trouble with this. I am using this code:

`OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT 
 sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART (HOUR, allValues.UTCHour) <= 12 THEN allValues.Measurement ELSE 0 END)  lessThan12
) bVal`

In the end of the Select statement of the view.

In the top select I then have following:
`CASE WHEN
  DATEPART (HOUR, allValues.UTCHour) > 12 THEN bVal.lessThan12 ELSE 0
  END`

It returns the error: `Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side.`

Comment: is allvalues in the from clause of the outer apply, or is that coming from outside?  because I see both bVal and allvalues in that statement.  Maybe paste in the whole query at the bottom of your question above so I can see it?

Comment: allValues is basically the variable name for all the columns in the view I have generated (which is simply a very very large select statement). So that means I have following:

`Select allValues, CASE WHEN   DATEPART (HOUR, allValues.UTCHour) > 12 THEN bVal.lessThan12 ELSE 0 
from
(**A VERY large select statment**) allValues
OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT 
 sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART (HOUR, allValues.UTCHour) <= 12 THEN allValues.Measurement ELSE 0 END)  lessThan12
) bVal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57328/discussion-between-kevin-cook-and-steewdk).